# Set up S3 bucket as website using ruby SDK

Tags: ruby, api, amazon-s3

I want to set up an Amazon S3 bucket as a website as described here:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTwebsite.html?r=5271

but using an ruby API, preferably the aws-sdk for ruby.
Is there a possibility to do that / a library that already supports that? Could not find anything in aws-sdk and right-aws, but maybe I was just blind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to configure your bucket as website using an ruby API. I did found a solution, but this uses the `aws-s3` gem, not the `aws-sdk` gem. I found this solution in the [ponyhost gem](https://github.com/jwagener/ponyHost/blob/4e04cf624ac0adc6ce26d95f0a848cc296a949a4/lib/ponyhost.rb#L45):

```
body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WebsiteConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <IndexDocument><Suffix>index.html</Suffix></IndexDocument>
  <ErrorDocument><Key>404.html</Key></ErrorDocument>
</WebsiteConfiguration>'

res = AWS::S3::Base.request(:put, "/#{bucketname}?website", {}, body)
```

**EDIT** you could also use the `fog` gem to accomplish this.

```
storage = Fog::Storage.new({
  :provider   => 'AWS',
  :aws_access_key_id => 'YOUR_KEY',
  :aws_secret_access_key => 'YOUR_SECRET',
  :region => 'eu-west-1'
})

if storage.kind_of?(Fog::Storage::AWS::Real)
  storage.put_bucket_website("YOUR_BUCKET", "index.html", :key => "404.html")
end
```

Comment: not ideal, but unfortunately it doesn't appear that the rightscale or aws ruby sdks support this without dropping to the http level.

Comment: I think it is possible to add this feature within `aws-sdk`. I didn't have time to complete it yet, but take a look at [this gist](http://gist.github.com/3712325). It raises an authentication error on `s3.client.set_bucket_website`.

Comment: hjblok - great thinking!  Using the appfog ruby sdk totally solved it!!!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Version one of AWS SDK for Ruby has the method `#configure_website` for bucket objects. So something like this would work:

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
b = s3.buckets.create(name, acl: :public_read)
b.configure_website do |cfg|
  cfg.options[:index_document] = { suffix: 'index.html' }
end
```

(the block to configure_website may be omitted if you don't need to set non-default options)

Comment: unfortunately this approach isn't working anymore with the current api. AWS::S3 is undefined ... Aws::S3 is a module

Comment: This answer was for version 1 of the Ruby AWS SDK that is still supported and still works fine. Use `gem 'aws-sdk-v1'` or `gem 'aws-sdk', '~1.0'` in your `Gemfile` to get it - or see the documentation for details.

Answer (score -3):

@Aljoscha AWS S3 is just a storage solution, to store all your files. It doesnt provide any kind of run time solution. You need to have a Ec2 instance to host your ruby based application or either to use ruby API. You can just host a static web site on S3 but cant run any kind of app.

Comment: Unfortunately you seem to have misunderstood the question. I want to turn a bucket into a website, using the above described Amazon API. I am looking for a ruby library that supports this operation on a bucket object. The code is obviously not required to run "on S3", as it is a storage solution only, just as you correctly remarked.

Comment: Hey Jeevan, Alojscha is trying to make the equivalent of this http request with a ruby sdk wrapper:  http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTwebsite.html